# Cannot install Xtreme Download Manager on Ubuntu 17.10 from NoobsLab PPA

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I want to install `xdman` on Ubuntu 17.10 but it's not installing.

I ran the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xdman
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that it is not packaged, so do the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://10gbps-io.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xdman/xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz
tar -xvf xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz
sudo ./install.sh
```

After installation you could find it in *Applications->Internet->Xtreme Download Manager* or launch it from terminal with `xdman` command.

**Note**: in [mentioned PPA (ppa:noobslab/apps)](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/apps?field.series_filter=artful) there is no package for artful.

Comment: (sudo ./install.sh ) it says command not found.

Comment: Did download finished? Do you have `xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz` file in *Downloads* folder?

Comment: ok its downloading just stay online.

Comment: i download it but it stay saying (command not found)

Comment: what .sh means ???

Comment: It seems that you need to learn GNU/Linux and commandline before asking questions. The steps above are straightforward, there is no place for error. Simple copying and pasting will end with xdman installed (they download file, unpack them - really only one file in archive - install.sh, and then install it by launching this file).

Comment: i goto downloads and right click on(open terminal here) then copy your commands, for download worked and it download file name is (xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz) but when i try (sudo ./install.sh) it says the command not found

Comment: @pomsky, no we do not `cd`. Archive has one file in its root folder.
@rateb. Do you have 32-bit system or 64-bit system? What is the output of `uname -m` and `arch`? What is the output of `md5sum ~/Downloads/xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz` (correct checksum is 043f4a9b94ee4fc493211260a3d794f6)?

Comment: i know that, I don`t use the first line

Comment: i have 64 bit system

Comment: uname  -m :    x86_64

Comment: md5sum ~/Downloads/xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz   SAYS :(043f4a9b94ee4fc493211260a3d794f6  /home/rateb/Downloads/xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz)

Comment: Thank You man i installed by a few more steps: (manualy i extract the file "install.sh"  on downloads directory and run the command (sudo ./install.sh) and it done. )

Comment: @rateb Those commands mentioned by N0rbert are supposed do exactly the same thing. I would suggest you to ["accept" the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future.